# Cannot display firestore info in react native view

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying ti display basic profile data from firestore on a profile page, but the information will not show up in the view. My code is below: I create a constructor with the state ethnicity

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
      uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      ethnicity: ''
    }
  }
```

And I then update the state with componentDidMount() as shown below and then try to display it in view

```
componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("profiles").doc(this.state.uid).get()
    .then(doc => {
      
      this.state.ethnicity= doc.data().ethnicity.toString();
      console.log(this.state.ethnicity)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  }) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>
          Mixee!
        </Text>
        <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>
          Hello, {this.state.displayName}
        </Text>
        <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>
          Profile:
        </Text>
        <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>
         Ethnicity: {this.state.ethnicity}
        </Text>

        <Button
          color="#3740FE"
          title="Logout"
          onPress={() => this.signOut()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The console.log(this.state.ethnicity) correctly prints out the ethnicity so I do not know why it isn't showing up. Any help appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are modifying state directly, with `this.state.ethnicity = doc.data().ethnicity.toString();` This [might not cause a re-render](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/), so your component does not update with the new state. Instead, try:

```
this.setState({
  ethnicity: doc.data().ethnicity.toString()
});
```

Calling `setState` will let React Native know that the state has changed, and that it should call `render` again, as explained [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried this but it is unfortunately it is not working. I tried console.log(this.state.ethnicity) but nothing is outputted. I am fairly new to React native so maybe I am formatting the state wrong or something else.

Comment: Nevermind! It was just because ethnicity was spelled wrong! Thank you so much this worked. You're the best

Comment: Whoops :) Sorry about that. I'm glad you figured it out!